# Setting a belongsTo attribute via an action on controller not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following models, customer:

```
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    //Other Attributes
    area: DS.belongsTo('area', {async: true})
});
```

and area model -

```
App.Area = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    zip_code: DS.attr('number')
});
```

And I use an Ember.Select view to show a dropdown of the area a customer is in -

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select_area" content=possible_areas optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name" value=area.id prompt="No area selected" selectionBinding="selected_area"}}
```

and the controller which wires up everything together -

```
App.CustomerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    possible_areas: function() {
        return this.store.find('area');
    }.property(),

    selected_area: null,
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            var selected_area_id = this.get('selected_area.id');
            console.log(selected_area_id);
            var selected_area = this.store.find('area', selected_area_id);
            var self = this;
            selected_area.then(function(area) {
                console.log(area.get('id'));
                var updated_customer = self.get('model');
                updated_customer.set('area', area );
                console.log(new_customer.get('area.id'));
                updated_customer.save()
                    .then(function(customer) {
                        //success
                    },
                    function() {
                        //failure
                    });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now here is the weird thing. Upon calling the 'save' action the first time, the line `updated_customer.set('area', area );` fails with the error

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('id', ) to the 'content' property of object proxy <DS.PromiseObject:ember551>: its 'content' is undefined.
```

Upon calling 'save' action immediately after that, the save goes through without any error and area of the customer is updated successfully. Although the dropdown shows selected_area to be null.

How do I prevent the first save from erroring out?

I am using ember-data 1.0.0-beta.6.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the association defined in your `Customer` model, I would remove the `selected_area` property from the controller and use ember-data's associations instead. Bind to the "area" association in the `Ember.Select` by using the `selectionBinding` property.

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select_area"
                    content=possible_areas
                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    prompt="No area selected"
                    selectionBinding="area"}}
```

This way, the `area` attribute will change when the user interacts with the select menu.

This has the added benefit of cleaning up your `save` action since we're binding directly to the `area` association for the `Customer`.

```
App.CustomerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  possible_areas: function() {
    return this.store.find('area');
  },

  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.get('model').save().then(this.onDidCreate.bind(this), this.onDidFail.bind(this))      
    }

    onDidCreate: function() {
      // Fullfilled callback
    }

    onDidFail: function() {
      // Rejected callback
    }
  }
});
```

However, the `possible_areas` property won't be populated when the template first renders since `this.get('area')` returns a promise. I would wait to render the select until the promise settles. You can do this in the routes `model` hook since it waits until promises settle to render the template.

```
App.CustomerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  route: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      customer: this.store.find('customer', params.customer_id),
      possible_areas: this.store.find('area')
    });
  },

  // Since the route hook returns a hash of (hopefully) settled promises, we
  // have to set the model property here, as well as the possible_areas property.
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model.customer);
    controller.set('possible_areas', model.possible_areas);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Feech, Thanks for the answer. The save works properly now. BUT, the selectionBinding doesn't work because it doesn't show the selected area, either on loading the dropdown for the first time nor after selecting a new value. It always shows the prompt of "No area selected". I tried adding `value=area.id` but still doesn't show the selected area correctly.

The save method still gets the correct area though weirdly.

Comment: Check my edit. I have a feeling this is a timing issue.

Comment: I changed the route as you specified. Same problem.

Comment: I added `console.log(model.possible_areas.toString());` in setupController which returns `<DS.RecordArray:ember444>`. I would expect a PromiseArray if it wasn't resolved.

Comment: `RecordArray` is what you want. I think the problem has to do with how you're using `Ember.Select`. Are you still using the `value` property? I would remove that and just use `selectionBinding`.

Comment: Yeah. I think that `RecordArray` is what we want. 

Nope. I am not using `value` property. but still doesn't work. :(